# PySpark: How to split the array based on value in pyspark dataframe, aslo reflect the same with corrsponding another column with array type

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe :

| ids | names |
| --- | --- |
| [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5] | [a, b, c, l, s, o, c, d, e] |
| [3, 8, 9, 3, 9, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8] | [s, l, h, p, q, g, c, d, p, s] |
| [9, 6, 5, 4, 7, 6, 5, 9, 2, 5, 5, 4, 7] | [q, a, z, w, s, e, r, t, y, o, p, a, x] |

I have two column which has same length of array, I want to split the first column array (ids) based on value 7 (inclusive) such as `[1,2,3,7,4,6,7] => [[1,2,3,7],[4,6,7]]`

if we have only one 7 then we will have only one array after split such as `[1,2,3,4,7,8,0,5] => [[1,2,3,4,7]]` after 7 if no 7 is there is have no use of it

also the same should reflect on another column (names) they are also splitted on the same index value of array and also produce the same length result as each id is attached with each names, hence we need to get the same split with **name** column same as **ids**

Output should be:

| ids | names | ids_splited | names_splited |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5] | [a, b, c, l, s, o, c, d, e] | [[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 7]] | [[a, b, c, l, s, o, c, d]] |
| [3, 8, 9, 3, 9, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8] | [s, l, h, p, q, g, c, d, p, s] | [[3, 8, 9, 3, 9, 0, 0, 6, 7]] | [[s, l, h, p, q, g, c, d, p]] |
| [9, 6, 5, 4, 7, 6, 5, 9, 2, 5, 5, 4, 7] | [q, a, z, w, s, e, r, t, y, o, p, a, x] | [[9, 6, 5, 4, 7], [6, 5, 9, 2, 5, 5, 4, 7]] | [[q, a, z, w, s], [e, r, t, y, o, p, a, x]] |

I have tried with many options but i am not able to get this resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your pyspark version ?

Comment: Spark version 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick solution with `rdd` + `map`

```
def split(r):
    A, B = [], []
    a, b = [], []

    for x, y in zip(*r):
        if x != 7:
            a.append(x)
            b.append(y)
        else:
            A.append([*a, x])
            B.append([*b, y])

            a, b = [], [] # reset
    return [*r, A, B]

result = df.rdd.map(split).toDF(['ids', 'names', 'ids_splited', 'names_splited'])
```

Result

```
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|ids                                    |names                                  |ids_splited                                |names_splited                              |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5]            |[a, b, c, l, s, o, c, d, e]            |[[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 7]]                 |[[a, b, c, l, s, o, c, d]]                 |
|[3, 8, 9, 3, 9, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8]         |[s, l, h, p, q, g, c, d, p, s]         |[[3, 8, 9, 3, 9, 0, 0, 6, 7]]              |[[s, l, h, p, q, g, c, d, p]]              |
|[9, 6, 5, 4, 7, 6, 5, 9, 2, 5, 5, 4, 7]|[q, a, z, w, s, e, r, t, y, o, p, a, x]|[[9, 6, 5, 4, 7], [6, 5, 9, 2, 5, 5, 4, 7]]|[[q, a, z, w, s], [e, r, t, y, o, p, a, x]]|
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That's awesome, it's a clear and crisp solution, Thanks @Shubham . Also I don't haveindex column as such and i am applying your split fucntion on two of the column not all so later if i want to join it then i do not have any index column to join or can i apply split function on partial columns and remaining dataframe will not get affected.

Comment: got it, I have sent all the columns and while iterating thru for loop i have added all  the columns and used only the required one.

It's working fine!

Comment: Great! Yes just use two columns in zip for e.g. `zip(r['ids'], r['names'])`

Comment: [Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12833166/shubham-sharma) do you have any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258564/pyspark-how-to-attach-the-new-columns-from-other-pyspark-dataframe-based-on-mul?

Comment: @praveenkumar I have added the answer. please check.

Comment: yes [Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12833166/shubham-sharma) yes I am checking now, btw brother thanks a lot, learning from you.

Comment: [shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12833166/shubham-sharma) as I see I have huge dataset, and dealing with rdd as comapred to dataframe is slow, can you comment on this.